# Script command won't accept results of array -join but will accept it when typed in manually

Tags: arrays, powershell, firewall

I'm adding firewall rules via powershell script.  When the script only wants to open a single port (i.e. when `$ports=@(80)` below) it seems to work fine, but I want to open multiple ports by putting more than one value in the array.

The script uses `$ports -join ","` to create the string `80,5000` but `New-NetFirewallRule` rejects the argument.  when I type `80,5000` explicity on the command line, then it does not error.

I'm a PS rookie, and have the feeling I'm missing something about the difference between what PS is doing internally and what it presents to me when I evaluate `$ports_a`. Here's an interactive session reproducing the error and the acceptance of the manually-entered value.

```
PS C:\Users\Steve\Documents> $firewallRuleName='Test Rule'

PS C:\Users\Steve\Documents> $ports=@(80,5000);

PS C:\Users\Steve\Documents> $ports_a = $ports -join ",";

PS C:\Users\Steve\Documents> New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName $firewallRuleName -Direction Outbound  -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort $ports_a
New-NetFireWallRule : The port is invalid.  When Protocol is TCP or UDP, individual ports or ranges are allowed.  Also, the 
following port keywords are allowed on Firewall Rules: RPC, RPCEPMap, Teredo, IPHTTPSIn, IPHTTPSOut, PlayToDiscovery.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName $firewallRuleName -Direction Outboun ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetFirewallRule:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [New-NetFirew 
   allRule], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,New-NetFirewallRule

PS C:\Users\Steve\Documents> write-output $ports_a
80,5000

PS C:\Users\Steve\Documents> New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName $firewallRuleName -Direction Outbound  -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 80,5000


Name                          : {09af142c-c82d-4329-aba7-60662f357366}
DisplayName                   : Test Rule
Description                   : 
DisplayGroup                  : 
Group                         : 
Enabled                       : True
Profile                       : Any
Platform                      : {}
Direction                     : Outbound
Action                        : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy           : Block
LooseSourceMapping            : False
LocalOnlyMapping              : False
Owner                         : 
PrimaryStatus                 : OK
Status                        : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus             : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource             : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType         : Local
RemoteDynamicKeywordAddresses : 


PS C:\Users\Steve\Documents> $ports_a.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                         
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: Skip the `-join` operation completely - the parameter is already expecting an array of port numbers, not a string containing a comma-separated list of port numbers - so simply pass `$ports` as the argument. You might also want to read [`about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Thanks matthias. I missed that you had commented when preparing my answer. The link about parsing looks very useful

Answer (score 2):

Gah. So the answer was: just pass the array in.  I don't need `$ports_a` and can just pass `-LocalPort $ports`.

A way to know this is the right way to pass the argument is via `Get-Help`: it shows that the type of `--LocalPort` is `String []`.

```
PS C:\Users\Steve\Documents> get-help new-netfirewallrule

NAME
    New-NetFirewallRule
    
SYNOPSIS
    Creates a new inbound or outbound firewall rule and adds the rule to the target computer.
    
    
SYNTAX
    New-NetFirewallRule [-Action <Action>] [-AsJob] [-Authentication <Authentication>] [-CimSession <CimSession[]>] 
    [-Description <String>] [-Direction <Direction>] [-DynamicTarget <DynamicTransport>] [-EdgeTraversalPolicy 
    <EdgeTraversal>] [-Enabled <Enabled>] [-Encryption <Encryption>] [-GPOSession <String>] [-Group <String>] [-IcmpType 
    <String[]>] [-InterfaceAlias <WildcardPattern[]>] [-InterfaceType <InterfaceType>] [-LocalAddress <String[]>] 
    [-LocalOnlyMapping <Boolean>] [-LocalPort <String[]>]
...
```